# How to use imread for big images on matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, bigdata

I have big a tiff file (2.19gb). When im using imread fuction matlab says 
"Requested 47937x51599x4 (9.2GB)..."
My question is how can i read and make my calculations on big image file like this?

Comment: You can convert tiff file to a raw binary format and in matlab using `fread` you can read the file partially and process the file part by part.

Comment: For that ı think ı need to Read All of image fisrt

Comment: As in Ozcan's answer stated you can use `imread` with `PixelRegion` option. If it doesn't work some utilities are available to convert big image files please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112162/converting-tif-file-into-headerless-flat-binary-file

Answer (score 0):

If it is a *.tiff image, then you can read a portion of the image with:

```
im=imread('img.tif','PixelRegion',{[1 100],[1 100]});
```

Comment: Thank you Ozcan. i will try loop it and process for my big data. I hope it works